# How to make a sql syntax that transfers data and delete the data at the same time

Tags: vb.net

How do I transfer data from table1 to table2 and removing that data from table1

here is my code:

```
 Public Class Payment
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VetSystemDatabase.accdb") 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Serafin\Documents\VetSystemDatabase.accdb
Dim sql As String
Dim sqldel As String
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim i As Integer

Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

Private Property dt As DataTable
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        con.Open()
        sql = "INSERT INTO [tbl_RegisteredRecords] SELECT * FROM [Register] WHERE [Price]=" & Val(PricePay.Text) & ";"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sql

        sqldel = "Delete * from Register WHERE ID=" & Val(Me.Text) & ";"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sqldel



        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
        If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Costumer has  Paid!")


        Else
            MsgBox("NO ONE PAID!")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
        loadrecord()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    loadrecord()
    Search.Clear()
End Sub
Sub loadrecord()
    Try
        Dim sql As String
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        con.Open()
        sql = "Select * from Register"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        da.SelectCommand = cmd

        da.Fill(dt)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Me.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
    PricePay.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(16).Value.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search.TextChanged
    sql = "Select * from Register where CellphoneNo like '%" & Search.Text & "%' or PetName LIKE '%" & Search.Text & "%' or TelephoneNO LIKE '%" & Search.Text & "%'"

    dt = New DataTable
    Try
        'open the connection
        con.Open()
        'bind the SQL and the connection through OleDBDataAdaoter and stored to da
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        'and whatever the value of da will be fill into dt our imaginary data table
        da.Fill(dt)
        'get the datasource of datagridview from our data table
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        'will throw an error if something went wrong.
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
    'close connection
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.Hide()
    DashboardAdmin.Show()

End Sub
```

End Class

Please provide the code because im dumb and my teacher gave us a sudden deadline and im desperate please help me. THANK YOU!

this text doesnt mean anything I need to add more text so I can meet the requirement of the post I am making

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What database are you using?

Comment: I kinda already fixed my code but doesnt completely do what it supposed to do.
what I want to happen is to transfer data to table1 to table2.
for example:
1. I enter Data to Table1
2. I click my button(this should transfer the data from table1 to table 2
3. That data I transfered should be deleted in table1 so it doesnt just stay there
4.That record is not showing in my table 2

I hope this makes sense. english is not my 1st language.
I am Using MS ACCES as my database. @Mary

Comment: 2 more questions. 1. Do all the column datatypes match in the 2 tables? 2. Does table 2 have an auto-number field?

Comment: Both tables have the same datatypes and everything. @Mary

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern for most database code in ADO.net.

First you need to verify that user input is correct. For numbers you can use `.TryParse` which returns `True` or `False`. If True, it will assign the converted value to the second parameter.

Keep your Connections and Commands in the method where they are used so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. A `Using...End Using` block will do this for you even if there is error. The comma at the end of the first line of the `Using` means we are including the next line in the block, in this case, the Command.

**Always use Parameters.** This will help you avoid Sql injection and make it easier to write the command text. We use the value that was set in the `.TryParse`, `paid`, instead of converting `PricePay.Text` again.

Don't open the connection until directly before the the .Execute. Connections are precious resources. It is closed and disposed at the `End Using`.

This may not solve your problem. See my questions in comments.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim paid As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(PricePay.Text, paid) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please put a valid number in Price Paid.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [tbl_RegisteredRecords] SELECT * FROM [Register] WHERE [Price]= ?", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PricePaid", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = paid
            con.Open()
            Dim i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            If i > 0 Then
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete * from Register WHERE ID = ?"
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    loadrecord()
End Sub
```

Comment: based on your code that you have given it looks like it has a user input. but actually the code I made already has given a fixed price. oh man I wish I could explain this in a better way but let me explain what my system looks like, so basically it is a very simple kind of system where you can just do CRUD where you can save, edit, delete yous data entries. so what it looks like I have this form where you can submit your information and it has datagridview (table1) and there is a form which the user can pay which also has datagrid view when I click that data there is a fixed price.

Comment: that datagridview also uses table1, and that form only has 1 textbox where it displays the price that should be paid. now I want to transfer that data to table2 because it was already paid and I want it to be stored it in some sort of record to the "Admin" can see it. I hope you can undertand this im sorry.

Comment: There is no mention of a datagridview in your original question. Unless you have set your text box to read only, a user can always change it. I suggest you ask a new question explaining how you originally filled the grid, show the code you used to try to adjust what is shown in the grid and explain how the result is not what you expected.

Comment: I am sorry if I am explaining this badly. I will edit the code I gave